# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'EventEmitter<Number>' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to write a service in which some events are triggered via respective methods in it so that any component in my application can listen to it.

So, I created a custom event in a service as follows

```
export class EventsService {

@Output() expandNav: EventEmitter<Number> = new EventEmitter();

trigExpandNav() {
this.expandNav.emit(1);
}

constructor() { }
}
```

Then I included this service as a provider in my component in which I wanted to emit this event via the trigExpandNav method as follows :

```
import {
Component,
OnInit,
Output,
EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import {
EventsService
} from '../../services/events.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
providers: [EventsService]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

eventsService: EventsService;

fun() {
this.eventsService.trigExpandNav();
}

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {}

 }
```

But I am getting this error

```
 ERROR in src/app/layout/header/header.component.ts(21,7): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'EventEmitter<Number>' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I don't know where I am doing it wrong, so please help and Thanks in advance.

IMPORTANT

What I am trying to achieve is :

Suppose I have 2 components. I want to trigger an event from 1st component when a button or link is clicked and listen that event in 2nd component from the html file like this sda

For that I made a service in which I am emitting the event through a method. The thing is it's working as expected.

Comment: Do you mean `eventsService.trigExpandNav()`? Or `eventsService.expandNav.emit()`?

Comment: Yes I mean      eventsService.trigExpandNav()

Comment: you probably want to change your EventEmitter<Number> to EventEmitter<number>. Number is a non-primitive type and is almost never used.

Comment: Please see the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using event emitters for Service's this is a better place for a RxJS BehaviorSubject or Subject. depending on your need.

`@Ouput()`s and `EventEmitters` are for Components only

So your service should become something along the lines of:

```
export class EventsService {

   private expandNavSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);

   trigExpandNav() {
      this.expandNavSubject.next(1);
   }

   get expandNav$(){
     this.expandNavSubject.asObservable();
   }

   constructor() { }
   }
}
```

then in your header component inject the service via the constructor with:

```
constructor(private eventsService: EventsService){}
```

and call the trigger expand nav function with `this.eventsService.trigExpandNav();` in your `fun()` function

Comment: Okay so to trigger this event I have to call the trigExpandNav() method and what do I have to do to listen to these events?

Comment: Subscribe to the `expandNav$`

Comment: put this in the ngOnInit of your component 
 
this.eventsService.expandNav$.subscribe(value=>console.log(value));

Comment: How?
And I can do this in html
     <p (expandNav)="someFun()" >sfs</p>

Comment: No, () denotes an event emitter. p tags do not have those

Comment: if you want to subscribe to an observable in your template you need to use the async pipe `{ observable$ | async }`

Comment: See my question again please I have updated it with a better explanation on what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: Hey man, having some trouble implement your suggestion. Can you pass me on a working code sample? @theOriginalJosh